# NetSuite Wookbooks Running Total Sales for this year vs. previous year

Tags: sql, oracle, charts, analytics, netsuite

I am trying to make a chart in NetSuite using Analytics Workbooks which shows sales for certain reps this year vs. previous year.

I've tried this in a number of different ways but it does not seem like this is possible without using formulas. I am not very savvy in writing code as I am just getting into this.

Type is Sales Order AND Sales Rep is any of ...,...,...,...

The goal is to have a shaded line chart for this year to date vs. last years sales for a group of reps.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

The closest I can get to a chart showing cumulative data is a column chart with separate measures for each month. This gives a year next to year instead of a year over year.

[image: Month Measure Formula]
[image: Chart Definition]
[image: Column Chart]

---

**Original**:

This formula will give you the criteria field for your date range:

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({trandate},'DDD') <= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'DDD') AND TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') >= ( TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY') - 1) THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END
```

[image: Criteria Formula]

Set this to "Yes" on the Criteria tab.

[image: Criteria Tab]

---

For the Series, use: `TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY')`

For the X-Axis, use:

Month: `TO_CHAR({trandate},'MM-MON')`
[image: Month X-Axis Formula]

Week: `TO_CHAR({trandate},'WW')`
[image: Week X-Axis Formula]

Date: `TO_CHAR({trandate},'MM/DD')`
[image: Date X-Axis Formula]

[Here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) is a list of TO_CHAR date options

---

Here is my chart layout

[image: Chart Layout]

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for the quick answer! It certainly helps. Forgive my ignorance, but do the "series" and "month" formulas go into the data set on the "data" tab? I do not see an option for formulas in the chart alone so I assume the formula has to exist somewhere else. When I add these formulas in the "data" tab and add them in the "chart", it only shows sales month-to-month, not cumulative as you depict in chart 1. This is an example of the kind of chart i'm hoping to make (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Having-trouble-making-a-YTD-Graph-look-right/td-p/118905)

Comment: This is another example. Let me know if the link works. (file:///C:/Users/lee.t/Pictures/2018%20vs%202019%20Cumulative%20Sales%20Amount.PNG)

Comment: Ah, cumulative. No, my chart does not depict cumulative. To show cumulative results, you would need an analytic sum with rows unbounded preceding windowing clause. You can do that in a Saved Search, but NetSuite does not support Sum in workbooks, and I have not yet found a hack. Sorry.

Comment: Understood; thanks for the quick feedback. I've yet to be able to do this in a saved search which is why I tried to use analytics. Would the formula be the same in a saved search?

Comment: If you need a chart, you can export the data to whichever programs in a dozen different forms. If you just need the numbers, This http://blog.prolecto.com/2015/05/26/solving-the-netsuite-cumulative-saved-search-tally-challenge/ is what you are looking for.

Comment: That certainly helps and I appreciate it. However, is it possible to make column 1 months (Jan, Feb, Mar..), column 2 2018 sales, and column 3 2019 sales? Each year with cumulative totals after each month?

Comment: I don't think you can do that within NetSuite. You will have to export your data and transform it elsewhere. Sorry.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help anyways! I'll be able to use some of this for other purposes.

Comment: The edit on my answer may get you close. With a measure for each month, you could create a pivot with year in the first column and cumulative data for each month column.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. That gets me a lot closer. I appreciate your help!